# Cannot overload << operator

Tags: c++, binary, overloading, operator-keyword

First of all this is the error I am getting:

> error: overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)
>       std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Dcomplex& c);

and i just don't understand why. I read several other questions and they all said to just add the const but its not working for me.

So this is my header file:

```
#ifndef AUFGABE5_DCOMPLEX_H
#define AUFGABE5_DCOMPLEX_H

class Dcomplex {
private:
    double re, im;

public:
    Dcomplex(double r = 0, double i = 0);
    Dcomplex(const Dcomplex& kopie);
    ~Dcomplex();

    double abswert() const;
    double winkel() const;
    Dcomplex konjugiert() const;
    Dcomplex kehrwert() const;
    Dcomplex operator+(const Dcomplex& x)const;
    Dcomplex operator-();
    Dcomplex operator*(const Dcomplex& x)const;
    Dcomplex operator-(const Dcomplex& x)const;
    Dcomplex operator/(const Dcomplex& x)const;
    Dcomplex& operator++();
    Dcomplex& operator--();
    const Dcomplex operator++(int);
    const Dcomplex operator--(int);

    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Dcomplex& c);
    std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, const Dcomplex& c);

    bool operator>(const Dcomplex &x)const;

    void print();
};

#endif //AUFGABE5_DCOMPLEX_H
```

I am thankful for any idea why it's not working.

Edit:

```
std::istream& Dcomplex::operator>>(std::istream &is, const Dcomplex& c) {

    double re,im;

    std::cout << "Der Realteil betraegt?"; is >> re;
    std::cout << "Der Imaginaerteil betraegt?"; is >> im;

    Dcomplex(re,im);

    return is;
}
```

Comment: `operator<<` and `operator>>` must be non-member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a regular operator override function within a class, the first parameter of the function is always the class itself. You can't specify another. There's no operator that accepts 3 parameters (except `?:` but you can't override this). If you want to write one with the first parameter not being the class itself, you can try friend functions.

```
class Dcomplex {
    // some stuff
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dcomplex& c);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Dcomplex& c);
}

std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& os, const Dcomplex& c){
    // Define the output function
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Dcomplex& c){
    // Define the input function
}
```

Comment: Ah now i got it and it works. But my professor never said that i need to use a friend function there, but it works and thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the operator is "this", so if you declare two arguments, the operator will actually get three - "this", and the two arguments you declared. It seems as though you meant to declare it as a `friend`:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Dcomplex& c);
```

Comment: Alright thank you that worked for the .h, but now i got the same error in my .cpp but i can't use friend there.. Sorry if these are stupid questions i just started with cpp. The .cpp is in my main post.

Comment: @HenningWilmer `friend` is just needed for the definition, not the implementation.